# OpenSource CMS for pdf files

Tags: pdf, content-management-system

I am looking for some opensource suggestions for a CMS which facilitates alot of pdf files. I have thousands of pdf files and I would like to use a CMS which makes handling these files as easy as possible.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Plone has great support for binary files like PDFs: upload, download, manage security/access restrictions, manage caching of them and have the PDF's full-text indexed for search out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your requirements, but if I were you, I'd store an editable copy of the CMS content (in HTML) and render it each time it is saved.

To render HTML in the best manner possible, use a tool like WKHTMLTOPDF - easily connected to PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I dont want to display the pdfs, they should be downloadable, more of a management system than a display system. Though users should still be able to have access.